# Ansible - to modify variables

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying to modify the values in the ansible variable as follows:

```
- name: Store edited data in file
  shell: cat "{{ list }}" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3 | tr -d ',"' | tr -d ',"'
  register: filenew
```

where {{ list }} is similar to :

```
    "alertname": "KubePodCrashLooping",
    "alertname": "AlertmanagerReceiversNotConfigured",
    "alertname": "ImagePruningDisabled",
    "alertname": "CPUThrottlingHigh",
```

Trying to get something like below, where only the names are displayed:

```
KubePodCrashLooping
AlertmanagerReceiversNotConfigured
ImagePruningDisabled
CPUThrottlingHigh
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the value inside {{ list }} and the desired output?

Comment: modified the data.  Please check. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the list,  and then modify each item like this:

```
- name: store edited data in file
  debug:
    msg: {{ item.split(":")[1].split('"')[1].split('"')[0]
  with_items: {{ list }}
  register: fileitem
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the data is stored in the file `list.data`, the task below creates the list `lines_new` with the names. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        lines_new: "{{ lines_new|default([]) +
                       [item.split(':')[1][2:-2]] }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'list.data').splitlines() }}"
    - debug:
        var: lines_new
```

gives

```yaml
  lines_new:
  - KubePodCrashLooping
  - AlertmanagerReceiversNotConfigured
  - ImagePruningDisabled
  - CPUThrottlingHigh
```

Best practice to create files in Ansible is the module `template`. For example, create a template

```
shel> cat filenew.j2 
{% for item in lines_new %}
{{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Then the task

```yaml
    - template:
        src: filenew.j2
        dest: filenew
```

creates the file `filenew` from the template `filenew.j2`

```sh
shell> cat filenew
KubePodCrashLooping
AlertmanagerReceiversNotConfigured
ImagePruningDisabled
CPUThrottlingHigh
```